# How to access value of a JSON object whose key is value of another JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I'm new to javascript. I have a strange requirement.

How can we access the value of an object whose key is the value of another object?

Ex:

```
Obj1 = {"name":"John", "age":30, "car":null};
Obj2 = {"John":{"country":"america", "job":"Engineer"}}
```

How to achieve something like `Obj2.{Obj1.name}.country` (result: america)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) like so:

```js
Obj1 = {"name":"John", "age":30, "car":null};
Obj2 = {"John":{"country":"america", "job":"Engineer"}}

Obj2[Obj1.name].country;
// or
Obj2[Obj1["name"]]["country"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access object properties using the square bracket syntax.

`object.property` is equal to `object["property"]`.

For your example, you can do

```js
console.log(Obj2[Obj1.name]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following
`Obj2[Obj1['name']]['country']`